# Quickblox voice calling / video calling

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

Does anyone know how I could use quickblox to make a voice calling/video calling? I'm making this app when the user clicks on the phone icon it starts the voice call between users and when they click on the video icon it opens them to video call? I just started working on it, I'm just wondering if anyone who tell me how to achieve the voice calling function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can mute video stream when you start a call in order to simulate audio call (the guide is here - https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/android-video-calling-advanced#disable-video).

Then if you need to switch to video call you can unmute the video stream. You can find useful this video calling samples - https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/code-samples#video-calling-samples